# How Would I Manually Uninstall Search Encrypt On My MacBook?

Tags: macos, malware

How would I uninstall Search Encrypt manually? I have a MacBook Pro and my toddler installed this bloody thing and it creates pop-ups and annoys me to no end. I have previously tried to find a way by simply googling it, but most instructions are specified for Windows and unclear.

Comment: Please add the system version and the browser to the question!

Answer (score 1):

Try using AppCleaner (http://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/). The Mac way of removing apps is to just move them to the trash, but that almost always leaves junk behind. AppCleaner helps gather that junk and send it to the trash, too.

Disclaimer: I'm not employed or endorsed my FreeMacSoft, the developers of AppCleaner. I'm just a fan. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

The Search Encrypt website has instructions for removing their browser plugins. Try this: https://www.searchencrypt.com/About/Uninstall